# Can I reassign the client account?

Tags: users, setup

I would like to give my client the client account, but first, I would like to assign my colleague as the client, just so we can see what the process looks like and see how our client will view Craft. Will it be possible to update the name and email address afterwards?

Comment: Is the issue that you don't know the client account's password? If you do, can't you just have your colleague log in with it?

Comment: @BradBell the issue is that I want to set up my colleague as the client so that we can see what it looks like from the client's perspective, then I want to change the email, name, password, etc to give to a client. I am creating a guide for how to use Craft, and would like them to have the guide before they have access to the CMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to initially setup the client account with your colleague's email/password/name.

Have them do their testing and when you're ready to give it to your client, either just update the email/password/name or delete the client account and re-create it for your client.

Comment: Thanks Brad, just wanted to make sure I was able to do that.